# How to keep multiple values ​received from user in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("task").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }

  document.getElementById("task").value = "";

  localStorage.setItem('data', inputValue);
}
```

When I enter new data I want localStorage to keep all data that I enter, but it stores only the last input. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to the right start, capturing the `inputValue`:

```
let inputValue = document.getElementById('task').value;
```

You will add this value to an array containing a list of previous, similar values.

But before you do this, it's probably a good idea to see if your `localStorage` entry, `data`, has anything in it, already.

If it does, that will be the source of your `array`.

If it doesn't, you can create an empty `array`, instead:

```
let inputValues;      // This will be an array
let inputValuesJSON;  // This will be a JSON serialisation of the array

if (localStorage.getItem('data') !== null) {

  inputValuesJSON = localStorage.getItem('data');
  inputValues = JSON.parse(inputValuesJSON);
}

else {
  
  inputValues = [];
}
```

Now you have an `array` to which you can add the new `inputValue`:

```
inputValues.push(inputValue);
```

And turn the `inputValues` array into a `JSON` string:

```
inputValuesJSON = JSON.stringify(inputValues);
```

And, finally, store the updated `JSON` string in `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', inputValuesJSON);
```

---

Why do we need to use `JSON` serialisation at all? Why can't we just store the `array` in `localStorage`?

Simply because `localStorage` will *only* store `strings`.

It cannot store data structures like `arrays` and `objects`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build it as an array or object into a text string then format it from there. Else you are just pushing the latest value into the local storage thus deleting the previous value. It's a bit annoying to do it like that, but it works =)

Answer (score 0):

This should be saved inside an array and on load should be fetched and displayed from localStorage. The problem is that you overwrite the value instead or appending/modify existing value.

I've prepared a sample to fix/explain the case.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ztb4m91v/4/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="task">
<button onclick="addElement()">
Add
</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  try {
    var storageData = localStorage.getItem('data');
    
    if (storageData) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(storageData);
      if (parsedData.items && parsedData.items.length) {
        var list = document.getElementById("list");
                for(var i = 0; i < parsedData.items.length; i++) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          var t = document.createTextNode(parsedData.items[i].value);
          li.appendChild(t);
          list.appendChild(li);
        }
      } else {
        
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
        console.err("Error while reading items from local storage: ", e);
  }
});

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function addElement() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("task").value;
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
    return;
  }

  

  try {
    var storageData = localStorage.getItem('data');
    var dataToWriteToStorage = {};
    if (storageData) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(storageData);
      if (parsedData.items && parsedData.items.length) {
                parsedData.items.push({id: new Date().getTime().toString(16), value: inputValue});
        dataToWriteToStorage = parsedData;
      } else {
        dataToWriteToStorage = {
            items: [{id: new Date().toString(16), value: inputValue}]
        };
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(dataToWriteToStorage));
    // Only add item to list once it's saved to localStorage
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    // Reset the input
    document.getElementById("task").value = "";
  } catch (e) {
    console.err("Error while saving item to local storage: ", e);
    alert("There was an error and the item could not be saved");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank y'all guys.
Actually, it worked by doing this:

```
  let arr;

  if(localStorage.getItem('dataX')) {
    arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataX'));
  }
  else {
    arr = [];
  }
  
  arr.push(inputValue);
  localStorage.setItem('dataX', JSON.stringify(arr));
```